# Does difficulty setting matter when playing locally against friend on Fifa

Tags: fifa-12

When you are playing your friend locally on Fifa 12 the difficulty setting is still there. Is it just a legacy from the single player or does it affect your other players.

If it does is there any recommended setting and why would you recommend it?

Comment: I'd imagine that setting should still affect the behavior of none controlled players, especially the goal keeper.

Comment: @yx What setting would you use when competing with a buddy locally?

Comment: I haven't played fifa 12, that's why I'm only commenting.  But I'd recommend a lower difficulty setting so the players are more important than the goal keepers.  If you manage to beat the other player, then scoring is pretty straight forward as long as you don't do something stupid.  Keeps the game fun with more goals.